# System.ArgumentNullException in System.Threading.Monitor.Enter

Tags: .net, multithreading, exception, monitor

I've got a code like this:

Some of our clients receiving "System.ArgumentNullException  in System.Threading.Monitor.Enter" in the following code block:

```
Public Class CheckStuff

   Private Shared SLock As New Object

   Public Sub GetIt()
          Synclock SLock
             DoSomething()
          End Synclock       
   End Sub
End Class
```

How can this be possible? Considering the `SLock` is shared, never touched from anywhere else?

Comment: Facing the same problem. Have you ever found any solution for this issue?

Comment: I also had this problem.  The solution was trivial - I had not instantiated the lock object.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you've oversimplified your sample code - it must be touched from something else to make it `Nothing`. Or, your locking method is called before `CheckStuff` has finished initializing. A stack trace would be helpful.

Comment: That's the problem, I've just look for all references and there is none. Also this never happened in our development or testing environments although reported from 2 clients.

Comment: System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(obj As Object) .. ThreadAcc.exe: N 00000 .. GetIt() ... called from GUI

Comment: @dr. evil: I'm afraid I have no idea what that was meant to tell me... please edit your question to give more information instead. (And then read through what you've written, pretending you're someone who doesn't already know what you're trying to say.)

Comment: You may find the explanation of this VB.NET behavior at http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/pages/7717.aspx helpful.

Comment: @DennisGaravsky: I don't see how that's relevant, given the code in the question - the `Shared` variable isn't local to a method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe similar problem - [System.ArgumentNullException in ResourceManager.GetString internals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323214/system-argumentnullexception-in-resourcemanager-getstring-internals).