# System.ArgumentNullException in ResourceManager.GetString internals

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, locking, resourcebundle

My code:

```
System.Resources.ResourceManager resourceManager = GetResourceManager();
string str = resourceManager.GetString("delete", new CultureInfo(1033));
```

In current project compiled under .NET 2.0 everything works as excepted. Variable *str* contains resource string for LCID 1033 - **Delete**, this is ok.

We are now upgrading to .NET 4.0, recompiled project under target framework .NET 4.0.
Now compiled as .NET 4.0 assemblies, it throws exception **System.ArgumentNullException** with message **Value cannot be null.**.Stack trace:

```
   at System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(Object obj)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo culture)
```

Interesting here is stacktrace, where it points to internal framework method in **ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet** which causes to call **Monitor.Enter** with null object. But i call method *GetString* with not null parameters *GetString("delete", new CultureInfo(1033))*.

This bug seems to be similar to [System.ArgumentNullException in System.Threading.Monitor.Enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655182/system-argumentnullexception-in-system-threading-monitor-enter). Maybe some bug in Monitor.Enter, or something else?

Update:
When i look in debugger at object `resourceManager.ResourceSets.Items[2].Value.Table["delete"]` then it contains string value "Delete". property Items[2] here pointing to LCID 1033. This means that resource manager already contains localized string for resource key *delete* in language *1033*. Does anybody knows where can be error?

Comment: Very interesting. I tried to explore the ResourceManager class in Reflector but I have only mscorlib 2.0. If it is a bug, I would search for it in ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet method. Are you using .NET or Mono? I would like to be of help

Comment: I am using .NET on windows, FW 4.0, just decompiled with Reflector, but could not find any unusual stuff in internal method. Take a look at this decompiled method here - http://paste.org/pastebin/view/25636.

Comment: Now i use .NET Reflector addin within Visual Studio to debug mscorlib, and find out that it falls in line 14 - lock (localResourceSets) (on pasted sample)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also think that you should declare and use your own dictionary for storage since ResourceSets is marked as Obsolete under .NET 4.0

Answer (score 1):

I found answer myself. Here are details:
We have custom implementation of ResourceManager like this:

```
public class DatabaseResourceManager : System.Resources.ResourceManager 
{
  public DatabaseResourceManager(int applicationID, string bundle) 
  {
    foreach (int languageID in ResourceProvider.Provider.GetLanguages(applicationID))
    {
      DatabaseResourceReader r = new DatabaseResourceReader(applicationID, bundle, languageID);
      ResourceSets.Add(new CultureInfo(languageID), new ResourceSet(r));
    }
}
```

In .NET 2.0 it works well, but in .NET 4.0 something has changed in implementation of ResourceManager.I think that problem is in parameterless constructor which in .NET 2.0 instantiate private field **this._resourceSets** (which is later used in *InternalGetResourceSet* for Monitor.Enter). But in .NET 4.0 parameterless constructor does not instantiate private field **this._resourceSets** and thus it fails later (as described abobe).

I must rewrite my custom resource manager as this to work out:

```
public class DatabaseResourceManager : System.Resources.ResourceManager 
{
  public DatabaseResourceManager(int applicationID, string bundle) 
  {
    ResourceSets = new Hashtable();
    this.applicationID = applicationID;
    this.bundle = bundle;
  }

  protected override ResourceSet InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, bool createIfNotExists, bool tryParents)
  {
    if (this.ResourceSets.Contains(culture.Name))
        return this.ResourceSets[culture.Name] as ResourceSet;

    lock (syncLock)
    {
        if (this.ResourceSets.Contains(culture.Name))
            return this.ResourceSets[culture.Name] as ResourceSet;

        DatabaseResourceReader r = new DatabaseResourceReader(applicationID, bundle, culture.LCID);
        ResourceSet rs = new ResourceSet(r);

        this.ResourceSets.Add(culture.Name, rs);

        return rs;
    }
  }
}
```

"Magic" here is that i must overwrite method *InternalGetResourceSet* to load my resources from custom storage (db) and return back "ResourceSet" for specified culture. Now it works like a charm.